# Strange Error with CGContext

Tags: ios, swift, cgcontext, cgcontextref

I am getting error

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
(lldb)
```

with this code

```
    var context:CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let radius:CGFloat = 5
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    var tempRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 20)
    let minX = tempRect.minX, midX = tempRect.midX, maxX = tempRect.maxX
    let minY = tempRect.minY, midY = tempRect.midY, maxY = tempRect.maxY
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, minX, minY)
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minX, minY, midX, midY, radius)
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxX, minY, maxX, midY, radius)
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, maxX, maxY, midX, maxY, radius)
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, minX, maxY, minX, midY, radius)
    CGContextClosePath(context)
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFillStroke)
```

I don't understand what the problem is. What  I am trying to do is create a rectangle with rounded corners in Swift. Why am I getting this error and is there a much easier way to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be CGContext, not CGContextRef? Everything loses its "Ref".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no current context. Thus `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` would like to return NULL (nil). You should test `context` in a conditional before going on.

Also you should type `context` as a `CGContext!`, since that is what `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns — a context, or nil, wrapped up in an Optional, implicitly unwrapped. Thus, when you get a context, you will be able to use it without using question marks everywhere. Even better, don't give it an explicit type at all; Swift knows better than you do what `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns.

Comment: And yes, there is a much easier way; use UIBezierPath.

Comment: Isn't UIBezierPath mostly depreciated?
Also, how do I pass in tempRect as context?

Comment: (1) Why would you think UIBezierPath is deprecated? (2) You don't pass a rect as a context. You have a context or you don't. If you don't, you can't draw. If you do, it has a size. You might be asking how to _make_ a context; use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions (if this context is ultimately supposed to become an image, that is). Or put your code in a place where Cocoa has already given you a context. See my full discussion of how to draw: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html